# Resolve NewtCanvasJFX from JOGL latest master

Tags: java, gradle, jogl

It looks like the JOGL team has managed to get JavaFX and JOGL working together [here](https://github.com/sgothel/jogl/blob/fc2edeb79e42897b926081769ad3cb3e509aed71/src/test/com/jogamp/opengl/test/junit/jogl/javafx/TestNewtCanvasJFXGLn.java).

But it looks like NewtCanvasJFX isn't available in JOGL 2.3.2.

How can I setup gradle to look at the nightly releases? Or would I have to download the JOGL sources to make that work?

Either way how do I setup gradle so it sees NewtCanvasJFX?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [the latest (January 15th 2020) RC build of JOGL **2.4.0**](http://forum.jogamp.org/JogAmp-Jbeil-RC-Build-2-4-0-rc-20200115-td4040267.html).

You'll have to wait for the final release to get it from Maven Central through Gradle.

P.S: Sorry for the reminder but StackOverflow isn't the panacea. JOGL specific questions should be asked on [our official forum](http://forum.jogamp.org).

Comment: Is there any way say using jitpack to get the latest instead of downloading the jar?

Comment: As in how do I add that build to my gradle file?

Comment: You can download jogamp-fat.jar and add it into your classpath: https://jogamp.org/deployment/v2.4.0-rc-20200115/fat/jogamp-fat.jar This should help you with Gradle: https://www.gubatron.com/blog/2014/07/29/gradle-how-to-add-a-list-of-local-jars-to-the-build-classpath/